# Ordering on the Cardinals - A Question About Set Builder Notation Using Cardinals

Tags: logic, notation, set-theory, cardinals

I'm currently reading Marker's text on Model Theory, and he constructs a set similar to the following,
$$ \{\alpha : \alpha < \kappa \}$$
where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal. He claims this set has cardinality at least $\kappa$. I'm a bit confused what this set refers to. I'm not very versed on cardinals, so specifically I'm confused on what the $\alpha$'s are. If the $\alpha$'s are also cardinals, then if we take $\kappa$ to be the continuum $\aleph_1$, wouldn't $\alpha \in \{\aleph_0\} \cup \mathbb N$, since those are all of the cardinals less than $\aleph_1$? In that case, of course the above set doesn't have the same cardinality as the continuum.

So what do the $\alpha$'s refer to?

Comment: $\aleph_1$ is not the continuum (unless we assume the continuum hypothesis). You should say where in the text you saw this, so we can look and see the context. (Answerers are probably right that it is the set of ordinals less than $\kappa$, but that's more simply just written "$\kappa.$")

Comment: This is in the proof of Proposition 2.2.2 in Marker's Model Theory.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  $\{c_\alpha: \alpha < \kappa\}$ is a set of new constant symbols of size $\kappa.$ There is a constant symbol corresponding to each ordinal less than $\kappa.$

Comment: Note for any set $A$ of size $\kappa,$ we can use a bijection between the set and $\kappa$ to write the set as $A=\{a_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa\}$  (as mentioned, $\kappa$ is the set of ordinals less than $\kappa$). This is a generalization of when we might write $A = \{a_n: n\in \omega\}$ for a countably infinite set $A.$

Comment: @EnricoBorba Marker's book has an appendix on set theory. If the meaning of this notation is not clear to you, you should read the appendix first!

Answer (score 3):

It should be described when the set is defined.  Most likely the $\alpha$ are all the ordinals less than $\kappa$ and it is true that there are $\kappa$ of them.  If we take $\kappa$ to be $\aleph_1$ (which may or may not be the continuum) it is the set of all countable ordinals

Comment: $\alpha$ is not referred to in the description of the set. I'm confused how we can compare an ordinal with a cardinal?

Comment: @EnricoBorba Cardinals are ordinals.

Comment: @EnricoBorba: Specifically, an ordinal $\alpha$ is a cardinal iff $|\xi|<|\alpha|$ for each ordinal $\xi<\alpha$. The cardinals are the ordinals that are bigger in cardinality than each smaller ordinal.

Answer (score 3):

It is the set of all ordinals $\alpha$ with $\alpha < \kappa$. In fact, this set is equal to $\kappa$ because for ordinals $\in$ = $<$ and every element of an ordinal is again an ordinal.

In other words, as sets we have

$$\kappa=\{\alpha: \alpha < \kappa\}= \{\alpha: \alpha \in \kappa\}$$